# capture frames from a video that is being recorded at the same time

Tags: android, video, camera, frame, photo

What I actually want to do is to capture photo and video at the same time. It may seem to be impossible, but I am wondering that is it possible to achieve it by getting a frame from the video that is being recorded, and then save the frame as a picture?

If it is, how to make it possible?
If not, is there any other alternatives?